# How can I create an incoming call screen for my app (ios)

Tags: ios, swift

I looked anywhere I could think of to find a tutorial or explanation for this but I couldn't find anything.
The app I'm building (for ios devices) has a calling feature, just like WhatsApp and Skype, and I want to pop a screen whenever an incoming call (in my app, not a real incoming call) arrives, even if the app is closed and the phone is locked.
How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: The thing you are looking for is CallKit.

Comment: @OndřejMirtes Thanks! But as I understand CallKit is supported only on ios 10 and above.. Is there a way to do it in earlier versions too? I mean, whatsapp and skype have this feature.. It must be possible.

Comment: ----------
Prior to iOS 10, there is no way to display incoming call screen as similar to native iOS incoming call screen, However, the only possible solution would be to use [interactive notification] (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/713/) which is introduced in iOS 8 +

Comment: Hi, Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Infaz, nope.. sorry.. seems like it's impossible in ios.
I haven't checked this since though, so, maybe something had changed in the past year